# Binding brother printer SDK framework to xamarin ios binding library

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, frameworks

I am trying to create a xamarin.ios binding library using the brother printer mobile sdk for ios (BRPtouchPrinterKit.framework).

The Xamarin.iOS binding project compiles and builds without errors, when you use the "BRPtouchPrinterKit" which is under "/Users/[username]/Desktop/BrotherPrinterSDK/bpsdkBinding/bpsdkBinding/BRPtouchPrinterKit.framework/Versions/A/" in mac.

When I try to use the dll in a sample and when try to run the same I am getting the following errors during runtime.

```
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__get_deleter(std::type_info const&) const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jgoldberger

For anyone who might be coming across same set of issues, Please go through the link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/340581

Comment: I have the working sample at https://github.com/ananthasivanvk/BrotherPrinterSDK_Xamarin_iOSBinding for anyone who wants to take a look or trying to figure out how you can integrate the brother printer sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is the same as this one on SO:
[Linking failure with a MonoTouch native library binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513979/linking-failure-with-a-monotouch-native-library-binding)

In which case you need to add a reference to libc++ (-lc++) and make sure that you set the IsCxx flag to true. This can be done in your linkwith.cs file in your binding project as in the post above, e.g.:

```
[assembly: LinkWith (... LinkerFlags = "-lc++ [and you may have some other -l* libs listed here here already]", IsCxx = true)]
```

If you do not have a linkwith.cs file, then you should be able to add the above reference to -lc++ and set the IsCxx flag to true in the properties for the framework. (Right click the framework and choose Properties)